# Canny: Lot of unwanted edges are detected

Tags: c++, image, opencv, image-processing, webcam

I am working on the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main()
{
    VideoCapture *camera = new VideoCapture();

    camera->open(0);



    if(!camera->isOpened())
    {
        cout << "No Camera" << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    Mat image,blur,canny;

    namedWindow("Video");

    while(true)
    {
        *camera>>image;

        imshow("Video",image);

        cv::GaussianBlur(image,blur,Size(7,7),1.5,1.5);
        cv::Canny(blur,canny,0,30,3);

        imshow("cANNY",canny);

        if(waitKey(30)>=0)
        {

            break;
        }

    }


    return 0;
}
```

This code generated following 2 outputs

Original:

[image]

Canny:

[image]

As you can see, the canny has detected LOT of edges which doesn't even exists. If this is an issue with the web camera frames per seconds, what kind of web cam should I use? how many Frames per seconds? I have tested this with the default web cam in DELL Inspiron 4030 and another USB 2.0 web cam. Both results are same.

If this is an issue with the code, how can I solve it?

My next target is background subtraction, and I feel that these unwanted stuff might fail me.

Comment: Try experimenting with the threshold parameters?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: I did. Answer is no :(

Comment: and experiment with  the blur parameters. It looks noise in the video is causing the problem.

Comment: Try a gaussian blur or median filter prior to canny edge detection

Comment: First, learn how Canny works. Digital Image Processing by Gonzalez may be a good start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have threshold1==0. If you set it to 10, and set the blur sigma to 4, most of those spurious lines will disappear. (at least they do for me).

With my webcam these setting get a reasonable output:

```
    cv::GaussianBlur(image,blur,Size(0,0), 4);
    cv::Canny(blur,canny,25,30,3);
```

However the lines detected are still a bit noisy.

**EDIT:** The following doesn't help: Another thing you could do is average two consecutive frames, that would reduce the noise to 70%.

(Or buy a better camera)

Comment: In case of camera, please advice me what to buy, it will help me a lot. This is my final year project, and I need to buy stuff with my money earned by freelancing.

Comment: @fatih_k the issue is noise, not dirt!

Answer (score 1):

Your low threshold value should be more than zero:

```
int low_threshold = 10;//you can try with different values
cv::Canny(blur,canny,low_threshold,30,3);
```

You can also play with some some camera parameters such as saurtion and contrast:

```
VideoCapture *camera = new VideoCapture();
camera->set(CV_CAP_PROP_CONTRAST,contrast_value);//between 0-1
camera->set(CV_CAP_PROP_SATURATION, saturation_value);//between 0-1
```

Comment: yes but that by itself probably won't fix the problem. The image is too noisy.

Comment: @user2151446, it may also smooth edges

Comment: I tried it. Fixing the threshold is not enough, more blur is necessary. BTW, the changing the low threshold won't smooth edges.