# How to get the average output of two consecutive frames?

Tags: c++, image, opencv, image-processing, camera

I am working on the following code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main()
{
    VideoCapture *camera = new VideoCapture();

    camera->open(0);



    if(!camera->isOpened())
    {
        cout << "No Camera" << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    Mat image,blur,image2;

    namedWindow("Video");




    while(true)
    {

        *camera>>image;
        *camera>>image2;

        //Show default image
        imshow("Video",image);


        if(waitKey(30)>=0)
        {
            break;
        }

    }


    return 0;
}
```

I got to know I can reduce the video of real time web camera output by 70% if I manage to [get the average output of two consecutive frames](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17125322/1379286). I got the two consecutive  frames using

```
            *camera>>image;
            *camera>>image2;
```

Now, how can I get the average of this and display it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `cv::Mat`, you can do it like this:

```
Mat img_mean=0.5*image+0.5*image2;
imshow("Average",img_mean);
```

Comment: awesome. I never thought I can do such simple image operations for camera output!

Comment: Many matrix expressions are available. Check the [documentation](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/operations_on_arrays.html).